# Make screenshot of window in focus without window`s decorations

Tags: linux, imagemagick, screenshot

I have to make an screenshot of active window's content (without window's decorations). I decided to use `imagemagick` and I know how to make screenshot of whole screen, but it i'snt what I need.

It also possible to use other programs, I appreciate `imagemagick` because it will be used in this script anyway.

Thank you for responding!

Comment: Look at `xprop` it will give you information about the window, especialy its position

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`import`, the screen-shooting tool that comes with ImageMagick, takes a `-window` flag that lets you choose the window you want to capture, either by its ID or name. It doesn't capture the window border by default. (If you change your mind and decide that you *do* want to include it, also pass the `-frame` flag.)

You can then use `xdotool` to find out the ID of the currently focused window, like so:

```
import -window "$(xdotool getwindowfocus -f)" /tmp/file.png
```

[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Taking_a_screenshot#Screenshot_of_the_active.2Ffocused_window)